# Import google service play appears with other file

Tags: android

Im just a beginner im  trying to import the google play service lib but its importing some more file not importing as a 1 single library file

How to get the library file as a single library file

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA87w.png

Comment: It's not a single file, you don't. What IDE do you use?

Comment: eclipse please check the image link given below how you can understand what im asking @EugenPechanec

Comment: Scroll away from samples till find lib

Comment: but how its automatically taking all files @minafawzy

Comment: i scrolled but there are no lib @minafawzy

Comment: follow this tutorial https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/integrating-google-play-services-on-android--cms-19828

Comment: or this Video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCGYxe4vbYU , all you need to import google play service library in project name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the import root to `C:\Eclipse\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject` and import `google-play-services_lib` project. Check *Copy projects into workspace* as you want to have a stable copy in your project when you update the SDK.